# GitHub file does not work in texstudio+textlive

Tags: texstudio

https://github.com/jiafeng5513/JLU_Dissertation

‘Cannot start or build...jlutex.exe’

Or can help put it up on overleaf pls? Thank you

Comment: What is jlutex?

Comment: That github contains a class called jlutex, why are you trying to run a program called that. Please explain in more detail exactly what you are doing